# Triple Nested Array MongoDB Query

Tags: mysql, arrays, mongodb, collections, javascript-objects

I'd like to find the correct query to return all Boards within the Boards collection where the member id matches 1. Any takers?

My schema as follows:

Within the 'Boards' collection,

```
      { name: 'Board One',
    teams: [
      { name: 'Team One',
        members: [
            { id: '1', name: 'Garrett' },
            { id: '2', name: 'Sarah' }
        ]
      },
      { name: 'Team Two',
        members: [
            { id: '1', name: 'Garrett' },
            { id: '2', name: 'Jeff' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },`{ name: 'Board Two',
    teams: [
      { name: 'Team One',
        members: [
            { id: '1', name: 'Garrett' },
            { id: '2', name: 'Sarah' }
        ]
      },
      { name: 'Team Three',
        members: [
            { id: '1', name: 'Jim' },
            { id: '2', name: 'Samson' }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

I'm trying to query a object within an array, within array of objects, within a collection. I've tried many variations on the following query..

```
Boards.find({
  'teams': { 
            $elemMatch: {
                          'members' : { 
                                      $elemMatch : 
                                          { 
                                            'id' : Meteor.userId() 
                                          }  
                                      }
                        }
        }
})
```

I'd like to find the correct query to return all Boards within the Boards collection where the member id matches 1.

Answer (score 2):

Could this be because you are storing id as string in the collection? As you will see below I tried your query replacing Meteor.userId() with a hardcoded string value (with single or double quotes) like '1' or '3' and I believe the query output is what you are looking for.

---

```
> db.boards.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("567443e7fba7a186bcd48bfd"),
        "name" : "Board One",
        "teams" : [
                {
                        "name" : "Team One",
                        "members" : [
                                {
                                        "id" : "1",
                                        "name" : "Garrett"
                                },
                                {
                                        "id" : "2",
                                        "name" : "Sarah"
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Team Two",
                        "members" : [
                                {
                                        "id" : "1",
                                        "name" : "Garrett"
                                },
                                {
                                        "id" : "2",
                                        "name" : "Jeff"
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5674441ffba7a186bcd48bfe"),
        "name" : "Board Two",
        "teams" : [
                {
                        "name" : "Team One",
                        "members" : [
                                {
                                        "id" : "1",
                                        "name" : "Garrett"
                                },
                                {
                                        "id" : "2",
                                        "name" : "Sarah"
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Team Three",
                        "members" : [
                                {
                                        "id" : "1",
                                        "name" : "Jim"
                                },
                                {
                                        "id" : "2",
                                        "name" : "Samson"
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
>
```

---

```
> db.boards.find({
...   'teams': {
...             $elemMatch: {
...                           'members' : {
...                                       $elemMatch :
...                                           {
...                                             'id' : '1'
...                                           }
...                                       }
...                         }
...         }
... })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("567443e7fba7a186bcd48bfd"), "name" : "Board One", "teams" : [ { "name" : "Team One", "members" : [ { "id" : "1", "name" : "Garrett" }, { "id" : "2", "name" : "Sarah" } ] }, { "name" : "Team Two", "members" : [ { "id" : "1", "name" : "Garrett" }, { "id" : "2", "name" : "Jeff" } ] } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5674441ffba7a186bcd48bfe"), "name" : "Board Two", "teams" : [ { "name" : "Team One", "members" : [ { "id" : "1", "name" : "Garrett" }, { "id" : "2", "name" : "Sarah" } ] }, { "name" : "Team Three", "members" : [ { "id" : "1", "name" : "Jim" }, { "id" : "2", "name" : "Samson" } ] } ] }
>
>
> db.boards.find({
...   'teams': {
...             $elemMatch: {
...                           'members' : {
...                                       $elemMatch :
...                                           {
...                                             'id' : '3'
...                                           }
...                                       }
...                         }
...         }
... })
>
>
```